# what's causing the layout to break? Attempting to make a horizontal layout website

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm trying to create a  horizontal layout following this guide here: http://www.queness.com/post/356/create-a-vertical-horizontal-and-diagonal-sliding-content-website-with-jquery Now it uses a mix of html, css and jquery to allow for smooth scrolling. I'm using the plugin and it works fine, however, the layout is all over the place, even though i've followed the basic maths of the layout.

My layout has 8 panels, therefore it's 8 panels * 100% = 800% for the width of the #mask container. Following that, it's 100% / n panels = 14.5% for the width of the container holding the content of the item. However, as I've just said the layout is horribly all over the place, and I dont think I've missed an instruction. I'm thinking it might be the h1 ribbon done in css that is causing the break up of the layout, but i dont think it is as I've removed it and it still looks horrible. I'm completely baffled by this, so I'm turning to you guys for guidance in resolving this problem.

Any ideas how I can resolve this? http://sekhu.net/charlie/index.php is the site i'm having the issue on. I've made sure the html is valid, and I'm using notepad for the html/css.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you doing changes? I am not seeing anything working at all

Comment: hi I am not making any live changes, I am trying to use the firefox developer plugin to see if I can change the layout. Otherwise I haven't changed anything and left it as is, so as not to confuse anyone.

Comment: And your code is horrible i try to figure out and I lost if I remove some div it shows some content. I would suggest you to implement this again carefully your code is wrong somewhere

Comment: ok i'll start from scratch and take it from there

Comment: Yes you should coz I got the same slider working and there are so many blank p tag in your code and so many unused element making me nuts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many unclosed div and p tags that's causing a big mess here

Please see my fiddle I put basic code of your just to make it clear.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ks5r7/5/

jsfiddle Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/ks5r7/5/embedded/result/

All you have to find now unclosed div and p tags everything is working like a charm.

Comment: yep you were right i shoudla just started from scratch i've got it working now on a second copy of the folder. thanks to everyone for their input and help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are changing the page as we are looking at it, so I'm going to stop troubleshooting.

What I did see while troubleshooting:

- The div "#mask" had the wrong width. It was my browser width X 3, not browser width X 8. Now I can't recreate this.
- I noticed that the demo site did:

  ```
  $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);
  ```

and you are duplicating the same code. I'm wondering since the demo site uses DIVs that are half the width of your site that maybe you could change it to this:

```
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 1600);
```

These are my initial impressions, but due to the site changing as I was looking into it, I'm going to stop here.

Comment: ah yes I am just dumping the demo site javascript into the page, without altering it, I just assumed that was to do with speed rather than width. I'm not sure why the page is changing as you're viewing it, as I am not on the site. Apologies

Comment: ok i tired the 1600 change, but to no avail. I must be getting the fundamentals wrong here, as I didn't think a horizontal layout would be this difficult.